# Return a value that was defined in map.forEach

Tags: java, json, lambda, java-stream, return-value

I have a Map named map passed as parameter to a function maptojson function i want to return the json for each k,v of the the map i have the following code .it shows the following error pointing to json "Local variable inputJson defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final"

```
public static JSONObject maptojson(Map map){
JSONObject Jsonobj = null;
  map.forEach(
    (k, v) -> {
       Jsonobj = new JSONObject();//Local variable Jsonobj defined in an enclosing 
                                      scope must be final or effectively final
        Jsonobj.put("key", k);
         Jsonobj.put(val, v);

    });
  return Jsonobj;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
new JSONObject(map);
```

That only works if your map is `Map<String, String>` but you can map (as in `stream::map`) your map from `Map<Object, Object>` to `Map<String,String>`

Comment: well my map is Map<String,List<String>>

Answer (score 0):

Don't return `null`. Instead return an empty `JSONObject` to indicate 'empty'. Then you can remove the assignment happening in the lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Use for loop, that will be easier. There is a reason why for loop is not deprecated in newer java versions.

```
    public static JSONObject maptojson(Map map){
     JSONObject jsonobj = null;
      for(String key:map.keySet()){
        
           jsonobj = new JSONObject();
           jsonobj.put(key, k);
           val = map.get(key);
           jsonobj.put(val, v);
    }
      return Jsonobj;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Imperative code is better in this case but even if you want use java 8 you can try like below:

```
public static JsonObject maptojson(Map<String, String> map) {
        final JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
        final JsonObject obj1 = new JsonObject();
        return map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(entry -> {
                    obj.addProperty("key", entry.getKey());
                    obj.addProperty("val", entry.getValue());
                    return obj;
                })
                .reduce(obj1, (o1, o2) -> {
                   o1.addProperty(o2.get("key").getAsString(), o2.get("val").getAsString());
                    return o1;
                });
    }
```